# Google Analytics Transport Beacon - No HTTP response detected

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to use `navigator.sendBeacon` as the [transport mechanism](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#specifying_different_transport_mechanisms) for my GA script in order to asynchronously transmit hits to the web server without having to set a hit callback. However, Google Tag Assistant is throwing a ***No HTTP response detected*** error when I attempt to use it. It responds fine when I use `'image'` or `'xhr'` as the transport mechanism, it's just when I use `'beacon'` that it throws the error.

Here is a snippet of my tracking code that I have implemented:

```
<script>
  window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
  ga('set', 'transport', 'beacon');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think tag assistant can pick up on beacon. Can you confirm if the data is coming through?

Comment: Ah, yeah I think you're right. The data is coming through. I tried switching over to use the Global Site Tag (gtag.js) and specifying the beacon this way: (`gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', { 'transport_type': 'beacon'});`) and it's working now without errors in the tag assistant. Thanks for your answer.